# After using .empty() div won't repopulate

Tags: jquery

After populating some divs according to users' selections I want to give them the option to clear the data and start all over.

To fill in the divs with an image and a caption I'm using:

```
$('#options img').click(function () {
    var imageName = $(this).attr('alt');
    var chopped = imageName.split('.');
    $('#titleImage').empty();
    $('#titleImage')
        .prepend(chopped[0]);
    $img = $(this);
    $('#_targetDiv img').attr('src', $img.attr('src'));
})
```

And the to clear all divs:

```
$('#reset').click(function () {
    $('div[id^=title], div[id$=_targetDiv]').empty();
});
```

But after clicking 'reset' to start over and choosing an image from the menu the target div remains empty, though the title caption does appear.  Why does that happen, and how can I correct it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've replicated this problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/tEkQb/1/

If your HTML is like my HTML, the problem is that you're deleting the element you are trying to update when you click. When you start out, you've got something like:

```
<div id="_targetDiv">
    <img src="default.jpg">
</div>
```

But after you click Reset, you call `.empty()` on the `_targetDiv` element, so all you have is

```
<div id="_targetDiv"></div>
```

Assuming that your `img` tag has a default, maybe a 1x1 blank gif (oh man, when was the last time I used one of those?), you should just be resetting the `src` to the default, not deleting the element.

Comment: You hit the nail.  I changed the src sttr to the blank.gif default img -I still use them often :)­- and problem solved.  Thank you for taking the time to help!